Aggregating rows in a table using multiple aggregate operations based on column name in R
I have a table with web site pages and their visits. In some cases there are rows that are duplicate. I want to deduplicate rows based on yearMonth and page columns while summing users and sessions columns.
| yearMonth | page   | users | sessions | bounceRate |
| --------- | ------ | ----- | -------- | ---------- |
| 202405    | a.html | 20    | 22       | 0.48       |
| 202406    | b.html | 14    | 16       | 0.52       |
| 202405    | a.html | 2     | 3        | 0.90       |

For column bounceRate I want to either use weighted average of those rows (if possible) or use the value from row with the highest amount of sessions.
| yearMonth | page   | users | sessions |     bounceRate     |
| --------- | ------ | ----- | -------- | ------------------ |
| 202405    | a.html | 22    | 25       | 0.48 (value of max)|
| 202406    | b.html | 14    | 16       | 0.52               |

I tried the script below but it always sums the bounceRate column instead of using the value from row with the most sessions:
data <- data.frame(
  yearMonth = c(202405, 202406, 202405),
  page = c("a.html", "b.html", "a.html"),
  users = c(20, 14, 2),
  sessions = c(22, 16, 3),
  bounceRate = c(0.48, 0.52, 0.90)
)

result <- aggregate(. ~ yearMonth + page, data, function(x) {
  if (any(names(x) == "bounceRate")) {
      x[which.max(data$Sessions)]
  } else {
      sum(x)
  }
})

print(result)


For the bounceRate associated with the maximum session value you can use slice_max from dplyr:
library(dplyr)

summarise(data, users=sum(users), sessions=sum(sessions), .by=c(yearMonth, page)) |>
  inner_join(
        slice_max(data, sessions, by=c(yearMonth, page)) |>
  select(yearMonth, page, bounceRate), 
    by=c("yearMonth", "page"))


  yearMonth   page users sessions bounceRate
1    202405 a.html    22       25       0.48
2    202406 b.html    14       16       0.52

For the mean bounceRate:
summarise(data, 
   users=sum(users), 
   sessions=sum(sessions), 
   bounceRate=mean(bounceRate), .by=c(yearMonth, page))


  yearMonth   page users sessions bounceRate
1    202405 a.html    22       25       0.69
2    202406 b.html    14       16       0.52


Using base functions we can split() the data frame before lapply()ing a custom function.
data.s <- split(data, ~ yearMonth + page)

# removing empty elements
data.s <- data.s[sapply(data.s, NROW) > 0]

fun <- function(x) {
    users <- sum(x$users)
    sessions <- sum(x$sessions)
    bounceRate <- weighted.mean(x$bounceRate, x$sessions)
    data.frame(x[1,1:2], users, sessions, bounceRate)
}

do.call("rbind", lapply(data.s, fun))
#               yearMonth   page users sessions bounceRate
# 202405.a.html    202405 a.html    22       25     0.5304
# 202406.b.html    202406 b.html    14       16     0.5200


Using by, maximum sessions,
> by(data, ~interaction(yearMonth, page), \(x) {
+   bounceRate <- with(x, bounceRate[which.max(sessions)])
+   data.frame(x[1, 1:2], t(colSums(x[c('users', 'sessions')])), bounceRate)
+ }) |> do.call(what='rbind')
              yearMonth   page users sessions bounceRate
202405.a.html    202405 a.html    22       25       0.48
202406.b.html    202406 b.html    14       16       0.52

or weighted.mean of sessions.
> by(data, ~interaction(yearMonth, page), \(x) {
+   bounceRate <- with(x, weighted.mean(x=bounceRate, w=sessions))
+   data.frame(x[1, 1:2], t(colSums(x[c('users', 'sessions')])), bounceRate)
+ }) |> do.call(what='rbind')
              yearMonth   page users sessions bounceRate
202405.a.html    202405 a.html    22       25     0.5304
202406.b.html    202406 b.html    14       16     0.5200


Here is another solution with base R by.
Write an auxiliary function computing all aggregate statistics. And call it in by. Then bind everything with do.call.
data <- data.frame(
  yearMonth = c(202405, 202406, 202405),
  page = c("a.html", "b.html", "a.html"),
  users = c(20, 14, 2),
  sessions = c(22, 16, 3),
  bounceRate = c(0.48, 0.52, 0.90)
)

fun <- function(x, na.rm = FALSE) {
  yearMonth <- x[["yearMonth"]][1L]
  page <- x[["page"]][1L]
  users <- sum(x[["users"]], na.rm = na.rm)
  sessions <- sum(x[["sessions"]], na.rm = na.rm)
  bounceRate <- min(x[["bounceRate"]], na.rm = na.rm)
  data.frame(yearMonth, page, users, sessions, bounceRate)
}

by(data, data[1:2], fun) |> do.call(rbind, args = _)
#>   yearMonth   page users sessions bounceRate
#> 1    202405 a.html    22       25       0.48
#> 2    202406 b.html    14       16       0.52

Created on 2024-06-22 with reprex v2.1.0
